# Powershell script: Unable to find Microsoft.office.interlop.Wdsaveformat

Tags: powershell, outlook, cpu-word

I have a script for changing signature in outlook. The script run fin on **32 bit** but got a Microsoft.Interlop,word,WdSaveFormat error on 64 bit. I have added :
`$wdTypes = Add-Type -AssemblyName 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word' -Passthru $wdSaveFormat = $wdTypes | Where {$_.Name -eq "wdSaveFormat"}`

But I got this error now:

> Microsoft.Office.Interlop.Word Version=12.0.0.0 Culture=neutral or one of it's dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Here are my bloc code:

```
$wdTypes = Add-Type -AssemblyName 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word' -Passthru
$wdSaveFormat = $wdTypes | Where {$_.Name -eq "wdSaveFormat"}
$saveFormat = [Enum]::Parse([Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdSaveFormat], "wdFormatHTML"); 
$path = $LocalSignaturePath + '\' + $SignatureName + ".htm" 
$MSWord.ActiveDocument.saveas([ref]$path, [ref]$saveFormat)
```

Can you please help?

The problem happens with Outlook 2016 64bit and works great on Office 2016 32bit

Comment: Assuming the first two lines work as expected, you can do `$saveFormat = [Enum]::Parse($wdSaveFormat, "wdFormatHTML"); 
`

Comment: I don't think they work good since I got a different error message

Comment: Do you run PowerShell with the corresponding architecture? (ie. `PowerShell (x86)` on machines with 32-bit Office, `PowerShell (x64)` on machines with 64-bit Office)

Comment: I run Powershell 64 bit with office 32 bit and it work flawlessly. However Powershell 64 bit with Office 64bit won't work. I have also tried the 32bit version of powershell and it didnt work

Comment: It looks pretty clear in that it cannot find the library(s) needed. Have you checked to see if you have a Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.dll file located somewhere nested in C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word? Do you have the library somewhere else on your computer?

Comment: I have verified and the files are there.

Comment: I don't understand.. _"The problem happens with **Outlook** 2016 64bit"_ This is about MS Word is it not? Do you have a 64bit Office installed?